Why does this Op-amp circuit output 0.75V at the ADC output?
Given this schematic, with a 12V feed at VCC/2, I was expecting close to 0V at ADC_IN, however it's around 0.75V. Ideally the ADC_IN would be zero when the inverting and non-inverting inputs are equal. This will be used to measure a current of 4-20mA, converting it to a 0-1V output, however this offset is way too high. Is the LM358 just not appropriate?


@SteKulov +1 for an extra answer for the LM7705. Low voltage (doesn't create problems for the ADC input), regulated and high frequency.

If this circuit was working as it should, then negative feedback would ensure that both inverting and non-inverting inputs have the same potential, somewhere near +3V in this case. You would expect \$V_{OUT}=0V\$. Then the op-amp would have to sink all current via R24, which would be:
$$ I_{R24} = \frac{V_{INV}-V_{OUT}}{R_{24}} = \frac{(+3V)-(0V)}{1k\Omega} = 3mA $$
That's too much for this op-amp (and many others, perhaps even most) to deal with under these circumstances. They simply can't get their outputs close to ground when sinking more than microamps of current, even though they claim to have "rail-to-rail" outputs, or an output voltage range that "includes ground".
We can see how close to ground the LM358 output can get, when sinking current, from fig. 5-12 of the LM358 datasheet (page 16):

As you can see, when sinking 3mA, the output won't drop far below \$V_- + 1V=+1V\$, which is exactly your experience.
Unfortunately, your goal of having this op-amp output zero volts is impossible, unless you endow it with a negative supply also, say -2V or beyond. Without such a negative supply, you can get closer to zero volts, but still never quite there, in two easy ways:

Reduce the output current requirement by increasing feedback resistor R24, and all the other peripheral resistors in proportion. If they were all 10kΩ, output current would reduced by a factor of 10. Whichever solution you eventually employ, you should do this anyway, since 1kΩ is too low for the resistances in an application like as this. In fact, try using \$R_{21}=R_{22}=R_{23}=R_{24}=100k\Omega\$, to see exactly how low the LM358 output can get in real life. Prepare to be disappointed.

Offload the responsibility for sinking all that current, by adding a resistor between op-amp output and ground to do some of the work. Call it a "pull-down" resistor, if you like. That resistor shouldn't overload the output when it's supposed to be up past +3V, so calculate it based on some maximum output current, say 5mA: $$ R_{PULLDOWN}=\frac{+3.3V}{5mA} \approx 680\Omega $$


You simply can't get 0V out of any op-amp whose negative supply is 0V, and there's nothing you can do about that. The obvious solution is to power the op-amp with a truly negative supply, well below 0V.
When driving an ADC, the simplest solution is to compromise. If you know that the lower output voltage limit of the op-amp will be +0.1V (which is reasonable to expect if output current were only microamps), then design the system to produce exactly that voltage, and not lower, and compensate for the offset in software. Sure, you lose 0.1V of the ADC's conversion range, but that's a small price to pay compared to building a negative power supply just for a single op-amp.
I am not certain, but I believe that is one of the reasons why the creators of the 4-20mA standard chose to stop at 4mA, not zero. It means that a current sense amplifier would never be required to output 0V (or lower), and could therefore be powered from single-ended supply. Another reason is that a system can recognise a fault condition (perhaps a disconnected sensor) when it sees significantly less than 4mA, or no current at all.

Thank you for the detailed explanation. After posting, this morning I considered adding a negative supply but really wanted to avoid that as nothing else on the PCB requires it. I'll modify things as you've suggested. Cheers.

@ScottPorter TI makes a product specifically to solve this issue and I’ve used it several times in the past with success: https://www.ti.com/product/LM7705

@SteKulov what a find, such a specific purpose! Thanks for bringing that to my attention

@SteKulov Consider adding an answer about use of the LM7705 to generate the negative rail, as it will add to the existing answers.

@SteKulov sadly my design days ended a long time ago. How nice it would have been to have such toys to play with.

The V- negative supply pin 4 of the LM358 is connected to GND.
Looking at the TI LM358 datasheet the VO Voltage output swing from rail parameter for the Negative rail (V–) is:


Which means at an output current of 5 mA the LM558 output can only typically get to within 0.75 V of the negative rail (GND for the case in question). For lower output currents the output voltage can get closer to the negative rail.
On option would be to change the V- negative supply to be less than 0 V.
A comment in the similar question Op amp output voltage offset too high has another suggestion:

You can search online for "Single Supply" op amps. Some have a "trim option" to help eliminate any voltage output swing – JohnnyMac



Is the LM358 just not appropriate?

It is appropriate, with understanding of how it works. LM358 has a class B output stage with a 100μA current sink load. The output stage does not sink current below 0.7V - all the current is then provided by the 100μA sink.
So to get the voltage down to 0V with apparent loading from the ADC, you'll need a pull-down resistor, or better yet a pull-down current source configured for a bit more than 0.1mA of current.
In practice, a two-transistor current sink works well, since the collector voltages on both branches of the sink are very roughly the same (0.7V vs 0V..3V - good enough for Australia).
The 1kΩ resistors are a bit too low for the weak output of the 358 - I'd suggest 10kΩ instead.
So, a circuit like this will work OK-ish:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

This will be used to measure a current of 4-20mA, converting it to a 0-1V output

I'm not sure how that is going to work, given that the circuit is configured essentially to do nothing at the moment. But I can suggest a slightly different one that will work reasonably well:

simulate this circuit
The current-to-voltage relationship is negative, but that's not a problem and easy to solve in the firmware. Both ends of the range are moved a bit towards 0.5V, so that they are well inside the 0.000V to 1.000V ADC range:

Here are the characteristics of this circuit:

The input voltage is a constant 1V - low enough to accommodate pretty much any 4-20mA transducer out there.

The op-amps operate well within their linear range, with minimal loading on their outputs. That maximizes their DC gain and thus the linearity of the response.

The ADC sees a nice relatively low-resistance source at its input. That is ideal for most ADCs out there.

The ADC input voltage is inherently limited to within 0V..1.5V range, for input currents of 0mA or higher.

There is no common-mode error that would depend on tight resistor matching. Conventional single-, two- and three-opamp instrumentation/differential amplifiers suffer from that problem.

R1 has constant power dissipation. It cancels the contribution of tempco to measurement nonlinearity. Once R1's temperature stabilizes, only the changes in ambient temperature affect its resistance, not the signal being measured.

R2 and R3 dissipate same power at all times. The top rail should be a nice copper plane so that they are kept isothermal. Their resistances will then track each other well. The absolute resistance then has no impact on the measurement.

R4 has uncompensated variable power dissipation. It is the most critical resistor in the circuit. That is unfortunate.


As far as current measurement circuits go, this one has quite a bit of precision for how simple the components are.
The circuit can be further protected against shorts to supply on the input by adding a series resistor between the transducer and the input, and a transistor-based clamp.
The 1.01V source can be derived from the ADC reference voltage, or any other suitable reference, e.g. by dividing down the output of the venerable TL431.

To make the output resistor balanced with R3, to maintain stable gain, we need to add another resistor - R6 - and control it so that the total power dissipated by R1, R2 and R3 is the same as the power dissipated by R5 plus the newly added R6. The layout needs R1, R2 and R3 connected to a good plane on one side of the board. Then R5 and R6 need to be connected to another plane of the same size on the opposite side of the board, or the two planes should be interdigitated on the same side. That way the overall power dissipated by the resistors whose ratios have to stay constant is equal.
This approach makes the circuit work reasonably with even crappy "Amazon special" resistors that have awful tempcos because the legs and endcaps are made out of tinned steel instead of copper. This is important if the circuit is to be used by hobbyists who are likely to get their resistors from dubious sources. It's an art to make stable circuits that work with low-spec parts :)

simulate this circuit

In all such circuits, the static gain and offset have to be calibrated in every device. I.e. you need to apply controlled 4mA and 20mA to the input, and have the MCU store the ADC readings in non-volatile memory. Then these range endpoints will be used to transform the ADC reading to current.
The firmware-based calibration is much easier to deal with than adjusting resistors. R1, R2, R3 and R4 should be 1% or better, metal- or thin-film. R5 and R6 stabilize the op-amps and are not too sensitive. 5% thick film will do for them.

"I'm not sure how that is going to work, given that the circuit is configured essentially to do nothing at the moment." Yes I modified the schematic (and tested) to demonstrate the issue with two (essentially) identical voltages resulting in the 0.75V offset. The actual circuit includes the shunt resistor etc, which would not contribute to this question. Thanks.

If you increase the resistors R21 to R24 from 1k ohm to 250k ohm the internal current sink (minimum 12uA but typically much higher) will be able to get the output down to less than 200mV. If we take the maximum Ios of 150nA the maximum output error (which will exhibit temperature sensitivity and change from unit to unit) due to the increased resistors would be 38mV. That's around 10x worse than the op-amp Vos, but might be good enough for you.
